# HTTP 1.1 - CONNECT method - How to determine end of response?

Tags: http, proxy, response, connect

Does anyone know how to detect the end of a response to a CONNECT request? I've been writing my own HTTP stack and have noticed that most proxies seem respond to this request in different ways, with none of them appearing to conform to the RFC. Specifically RFC 2616 section 4.4:

```
   1.Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such
     as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD
     request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the
     header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in
     the message.

   2.If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
     has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
     defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
     unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.

   3.If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
     decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
     transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
     if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
     header field is present). If a message is received with both a
     Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
     the latter MUST be ignored.

   4.If the message uses the media type "multipart/byteranges", and the
     ransfer-length is not otherwise specified, then this self-
     elimiting media type defines the transfer-length. This media type
     UST NOT be used unless the sender knows that the recipient can arse
     it; the presence in a request of a Range header with ultiple byte-
     range specifiers from a 1.1 client implies that the lient can parse
     multipart/byteranges responses.

       A range header might be forwarded by a 1.0 proxy that does not
       understand multipart/byteranges; in this case the server MUST
       delimit the message using methods defined in items 1,3 or 5 of
       this section.

   5.By the server closing the connection. (Closing the connection
     cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since that
     would leave no possibility for the server to send back a response.)
```

Assuming the proxy supports the CONNECT method and aren't blacklisting the host/port I am trying to connect to, they return status code 200 which could in theory could contain a message body, so I cant use method 1. None of the proxies i've tested contained headers which would allow me to use methods 2-4. And because the connection has to stay open since the CONNECT method provides behavior similar to a SOCKS proxy, I cant use method 5. The closest I've seen is Fiddler (and possibly other) proxies send a Connection: close header even though they dont actually close the connection, since this is the closest thing they could do to support method #5. And some proxies dont even provide any headers, just a status line followed by a CR/LF.

Is there a special way you're supposed to handle these responses that is defined in a another RFC, or in a section which i've managed to overlook? Section 9.9 of the RFC which defines the CONNECT method is severely lacking in specifying how this method should be handled as it is only a single sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like in the new proposed RFC they do define how CONNECT responses are to be handled. That they can not contain a message body, and you determine the end of the response by a empty line (CR/LF)

http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#CONNECT

Answer (score 0):

There is no real body. All CONNECT request and response do is to establish a tunnel which ends with connection close. See [RFC2817](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt) for the specification.